# multi level array using elemnt indent value in xml in php?

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, parent-child

From following XML of items having title and indent value

```
<items>
  <item>
    <title>Module 1</title>
    <indent>0</indent>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Module 2</title>
    <indent>1</indent>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Module 3</title>
    <indent>2</indent>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Module 4</title>
    <indent>2</indent>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Module 5</title>
    <indent>1</indent>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Module 6</title>
    <indent>0</indent>
  </item>
</items>
```

Need a multidimensional array with parent-child  relation depends

```
    [
    {
    "title": "Module 1",
    "children": [
       {
        "title": "Module 2",
        "children": [
            {
              "title": "Module 3",
              "children": []
            },
            {
                "title": "Module 4",
                "children": []
            }
        ]},
        {
            "title": "Module 5",
            "children": []
        }
        ]
    },
    {
    "title": "Module 5",
    "children": []
    }
    ]
```

Here indent value in XML will decide if array child/sibling of earlier xml item and serialization of item shouldn't break.

I tried many logic but not getting that right.A hint on logic would be helpful.
thanks in advance

What i have tried till now

```
foreach($xml_array as $item){
            $children['title'] =  html_entity_decode($item->title);
            $children['indent'] =  html_entity_decode($item->indent);
            $indent = html_entity_decode($item->indent);
            if($indent == 0 ){
                $toc_array[$section_counter]['children'][] = $children;
                end($toc_array[$section_counter]['children']);
                $last_indent_0_key =  key($toc_array[$section_counter]['children']);
            }else if($indent == 1){
                $toc_array[$section_counter]['children'][$last_indent_0_key]['children'][] = $children;
                end($toc_array[$section_counter]['children'][$last_indent_0_key]['children']);
                $last_indent_1_key =  key($toc_array[$section_counter]['children'][$last_indent_0_key]['children']);
            }else if($indent == 2){
                $toc_array[$section_counter]['children'][$last_indent_0_key]['children'][$last_indent_1_key]['children'][] = $children;
                end($toc_array[$section_counter]['children'][$last_indent_0_key]['children'][$last_indent_1_key]['children']);
                $last_indent_2_key =  key($toc_array[$section_counter]['children'][$last_indent_0_key]['children'][$last_indent_1_key]['children']);
            }
            $last_indent = html_entity_decode($item->indent);

        }
```

This code gives me what i want but indent value could be up to 10 .
Want to minimize this code using for / foreach loop as above code is never a good practice.

Comment: And how much are you willing to pay for this job?

Comment: I am new to stack if anything wrong in question please let me know.

Comment: You should show us what have you tried first.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You are supposed to show us what you have tried already.